# use field that does not exsit in the model in the erb file

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My model `User` contains only field `hashed_password` but not `password` and `confirmed_password`, which are requested to provide when registering. How should I write the view in this case? Following code will generate error `Model User does not respond to password`.

```
17:   </div>
18:   <div class="field">
19:     <%= f.label :password %><br />
20:     <%= f.text_field :password %>
21:   </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

But if it's fot authentication problem, you should probably use some sort of libs, like [authlogic](http://github.com/binarylogic/authlogic)  or [devise](http://github.com/plataformatec/devise), both these library would provide you with this virtual attributes.

Answer (score 2):

What you're looking for is called a **virtual attribute**. There's a good screencast on Railscasts that covers this: [Railscasts - Virtual Attributes](http://railscasts.com/episodes/16-virtual-attributes)

Edit: In the case of your `password` and `confirmed_password` fields, you'll also want to look into [filtering sensitive data from the request log](http://rails.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Base.html#M000453) as well using `filter_parameter_logging`.